# UILocalNotification setTimeZone to AM/PM

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification, nstimezone

How to set **timeZone** for `UILocalNotification` to AM/PM.

Comment: what do you mean by timezone in localnotification, please post the problem that you are having

Comment: please see your UILocalNotification code

Comment: use localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; your device time zone set

Comment: what does timezone have to do with AM/PM???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];